# How do I get Edge to work in an Android phone with Selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

I know that it is possible to make Chrome work in Android phone using selenium.

Is there a way to do this with Microsoft Edge?

I have the next code in python.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

options = webdriver.Edge()
options.add_experimental_option("androidPackage", "com.android.edge")
driver = webdriver.Edge("./msedgedriver", options=options)
driver.get("https://bing.com")
time.sleep(100)
driver.quit() 
# out => AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'add_experimental_option'
```

It will launch Edge on the PC instead of on mobile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use **webdriver.EdgeOptions()** to define EdgeOptions instead of `webdriver.Edge()` when using selenium webdriver.

And the relevant error has been mentioned in the code you provided:

```
'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'add_experimental_option'
```

Unfortunately I don't know much about Android development, but I'm sure that the webdriver.EdgeOptions() object can call the `add_experimental_option` method.

Answer (score 0):

You have to import and configure `options` for the `Edge` driver properly.
I'm not sure about the `androidPackage` specifically, but your code should be something like this:

```py
from msedge.selenium_tools import EdgeOptions
from msedge.selenium_tools import Edge

edge_options = EdgeOptions()
edge_options.add_experimental_option("androidPackage", "com.android.edge")
driver = Edge(executable_path="./msedgedriver", options=edge_options)
driver.get("https://bing.com")
time.sleep(1000)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: It`s not works. When I run the script, its launch Edge on Windows

Comment: And what are you expecting to occur?

Comment: I need to launch Edge on my android.
I know how to do it with Chrome:
https://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started/getting-started---android